# Remove quote marks in Google Cloud Datalab SQL module parameters?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

The parameterization example in the "SQL Parameters" IPython notebook in the datalab github repo (under datalab/tutorials/BigQuery/) shows how to change the value being tested for in a WHERE clause.

```
%%sql --module get_data
SELECT *
FROM
    [myproject:mydataset.mytable]
WHERE
    $query
```

However, this syntax always seems to insert quotation marks around the parameter. This breaks when I pass parameters that aren't just a simple value:

```
import gcp.bigquery as bq
query = "(bnf_code LIKE '1202%') OR (bnf_code LIKE '1203%')"
query = bq.Query(get_data, query=query)

print query.sql
```

This prints an invalid query:

```
SELECT * FROM [myproject:mydataset.mytable]
WHERE "(bnf_code LIKE '1202%') OR (bnf_code LIKE '1203%')"
```

Is there any way I can insert values that aren't wrapped in quotation marks?

I'm using the module repeatedly in my code, with variable numbers of OR clauses in the query parameter. So I do need a way to pass in more complicated queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, variables are meant to be simple scalars, or tables, or (soon) lists for use in IN clauses. They are not meant for expressions.

Comment: Is there a relevant Public Issue Tracker for Datalab where a Feature Request could be filed? This seems to be a Datalab issue in terms of how it templates variables into queries, and not a BigQuery issue, correct?

Comment: Plus-1 for having an issue tracker where this could be filed.

Comment: @Pentium10 I've worked around it by making the query a Python string instead of a submodule, and then just calling it with `bq.Query(query_string)` with no variables. It's messy though.

Comment: However, as this is by design, filing an issue is not going to achieve much. Richard, lists will be supported in next release (the code is in main already).

Answer (score 2):

Passing unquoted arguments to SQL *modules* isn't possible, but it is possible to create a `datalabs.data.SQLStatement` with straight-up SQL in string form. With that you can use your own, Python-style placeholders to substitute values as you see fit:

```
import datalab.data._sql_statement as bqsql
statement = bqsql.SqlStatement(
    "SELECT some-field FROM %s" % '[your-instance:some-table-name]')
query = bq.Query(statement)
```

I don't know if they're doing anything special with placeholders or the in-notebook command processing but... well, I didn't see any of that in my (admittedly limited) spelunking.